Ошибка "programmer is not responding" при компиляции для Arduino Nano
Я работаю в linux mint Arduno IDE. Когда компилирую Arduino Nano через порт /dev/ttyS4 вылезает ошибка:
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

Вот код программы:
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); //set Serial output baud rate
  Serial.println("\nVoltage(V):");
  Serial.print("--------------------------------------------------\n");
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    int anaValue = analogRead(0); 
    float voltage = 5 -(anaValue/1024.0)*5;
    Serial.println(voltage);
    if (voltage >0.08 or voltage<0.03){
      Serial.println("ERROR");
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    }
}

Как я понял код у меня правильный, а проблема либо в плате, либо в компьютере.
Я пробовал вместо процессора Atmega328P поставить Atmega328P (Old Bootloader), но не работает.
